# Merging data from two columns into one SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to merge data from two rows into one, for example:

```
EmpID  Start    Title                 Row   
-----------------------------------------
  123  2021     'data architect'       2
  123  2022     'I.T manager'          1
```

And the result I'm expecting is:

```
EmpID  Start    Title                 Previous_title
-----------------------------------------------------
  123  2022     'I.T manager'          Data Architect
```

What I'm thinking is that I can take each result and merge them by creating temporary tables but I'm trying to avoid those steps to keep the code as clean as possible because I have already created more than 3 temp tables to get to this result.

Any suggestion is well appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if a single `EmpID` has three or more distinct `Title` values?

Comment: `MIN(CASE WHEN [Row] = 2 THEN Title END)` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `lag` and `row_number` to give you the the title and previous title for each EmpID, assuming there are at least a few, and you can change the `where` clause in case you want to know more than the current and previous title for each EmpID

```
select EmpID,
       Start,
       Title,
       Previous_title
from   (
        select EmpID
              ,Start
              ,Title
              ,lag(Title)    over(partition by EmpID order by start)      as Previous_title  
              ,row_number () over(partition by EmpID order by start desc) as rn
        from t
       ) t
where rn = 1
```

| EmpID | Start | Title | Previous_title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022 | 'I.T manager' | 'data architect' |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9cb045b8b320d739c960e1a7814ac71&hide=1)